# not able to execute shell script

Tags: java, linux

I've scenario where I execute my java code using shell script.

When I run that shell script from autosys, it runs fine. But when I try to run it manually from linux box, it says `Java not found` error.

And when I check manually java version in linux box, using `java -version` it says java not there.

How its possible that, same shell script is triggered by Autosys but not manually ?

May I know please, what type of configuration is this ? I'm I missing anything ?

Comment: What PATH does autosys have set?

Comment: that I dont have accessto check but trigger only, but when I do echo $PATH, returns multiple bin paths

Comment: That environment variable should be named `PATH`, not `PAATH`. Try changing that.

Comment: sorry that was echo $PATH only, typo error

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Java could be installed for the autosys user only in which case it will not be accessible by another user.

The autosys user could have had some PATH variable (perhaps in the profile) that points to the Java binary, which might not be present in your current user. You might want to check your `~/.profile` file (or) `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` to see if there is `PATH` variable.

***To debug***, just include `which java` in your shell script and check the output when the autosys runs it. This will give you the path of the java binary.

(or) Simply login as your autosys user and execute the same script.

May be, you might also be missing some *bootstrap* commands before executing your script (like `export PATH` etc).